# Constant Current and Constant voltage

Tags: power-supply, constant-current

I have this [Power Supply](https://www.tanotis.com/products/gw-instek-gpc-3030d-bench-power-supply-adjustable-fixed-3-output-0-v-30-v-0-a-3-a?gclid=Cj0KCQjw9fntBRCGARIsAGjFq5ER31pyV5BvyQJhfpCk0mudsmCBTrzqk4Exxu5z22mkamrOU1fTJC8aAvlWEALw_wcB)

There are two modes, Constant current and constant voltage.

When does this two modes come into picture under which circumstances.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Read this: http://powersupply.blogs.keysight.com/search?q=CC+CV

Comment: It's often implemented as a simple voltage regulator with a current limit circuit added to provide feedback if the current exceeds some given limit. So just think if it as a simple voltage regulator that includes a current monitor. When the current exceeds some limit, feedback is used to lower the voltage being regulated so that the current limit is obeyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you haven't noticed:

- Voltage-limiting on = constant voltage
- Current-limiting on = constant current

Both functions are always ever-present and will kick in whenever needed. The one whose limit is hit first based on the load that is connected will be the one to kick in. That means one of them is ALWAYS on.

For example, suppose you connect a load and set a voltage and current.

If the voltage limit will kicks in, then current that would drawn by the load at the set voltage is below the configured current limit. This results in a constant voltage supply.

If the load would draw more current than the configured current at the configured voltage, then the current limit kicks in. This results in a constant current supply.

Convenient, no?

EDIT:

The voltage and current displays on the supply probably only display the actual values of voltage and current the supply is providing. If you want to see the "set" value for the voltage or current limit thresholds, you have to work around this.

The current limiting works by reducing the voltage to a point where the current drawn by the load is equal to the constant current limit. That means if you make sure current limiting isn't on, then the actual output voltage is equal to the voltage limit threshold.

That means in order to read the voltage limit threshold off the display, you have to make sure current limiting is not active. The easiest way to do this is to disconnect the load. You may have to turn the current knob a bit past zero since some supplies interpret a current knob turned all the way down as "off" and will kill the supply voltage even if no current is being drawn.

Similarly, to see the current limit, you just have to connect a load and turn up the voltage until the output voltage stops increasing. That means the current drawn by the load at the attempted output voltage exceeds the current limit threshold. The output voltage is not allowed to increase because current limiting has kicked in. At that point, the actual output current on the display is equal to the current limit threshold.

Obviously, that means always start your BOTH knobs LOW and alternately turn up each one a bit so that they  slowly more or less together until you have a good idea of what you are able to get away with for your load. Never start high or you can damage something.

Comment: thank you, i got some clarity. Could you just provide some example numbers too. And when you set a voltage in the power supply mentioned in my question, I dont set any current. the current consumed from the power supply is determined only by the load right? then how can we set a current in the power supply

Comment: @Newbie if you buy a power supply with an adjustable current limit it will have some way to adjust the limit. Could be a knob on the front panel.  Could be typing on its keyboard. Could be hooking up a resistor to two terminals. Consult the manual for your supply.

Comment: @Newbie, yours has two knobs labelled "current". I'll bet they have something to do with setting the current limit.

Comment: @Newbie See additions to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage limit is understood by users as that is normally set to what  your circuit needs.

The current limit is most often used to protect the connected circuit.

For example: you have designed a circuit which you expect has a max 100mA current usage and have set the supply current limit to that value. If there is a short/fault somewhere in the design your voltage will drop to limit the current to 100mA hopefully reducing the energy so much that your circuit survives.

Note that together they limit the maximum *power* which can come out. Set it to 5V and 100mA and the maximum power coming out is 0.5Watts.

(I have used the current limit to charge my car battery when I have left the door ajar again the whole nigh)